# My Ajax script sets a variable Task_Number equal to the tasknumber of the row I clicked on, but my php shows it as an undefined index

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a Table, when I click on a row I want a modal to pop up with data from the database. I have an ajax request that onclick gets the value of the Task Number that I clicked on and then sends the task number to a php file where I use it to get the rest of the data in the database. I keep getting a php error where my variable is undefined.

Tried using var Task_Number = $(this).data('data');  and var Task_Number = $(this).data('data-value');

```
 <table class="taskTable"  >
 <tbody class="task-tbody">

            <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($Table)){ $task123=$row1[2];  ?>
            <tr class = "task-tr" data-value="<?php echo $task123;?>"  onclick="myFunction()">
                <td class="task-td"><input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php if ($row1[0]=='backlog') {$statuscss= 'statusBacklog';} elseif ($row1[0]== 'inprogress') {$statuscss= 'statusInProgress';} else{ $statuscss= 'statusDone';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?><?php echo $row1[0];?></div></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php if ($row1[1]=='HIGH') {$statuscss= 'priorityHigh';} elseif ($row1[1]== 'MEDIUM') {$statuscss= 'priorityMedium ';} else{ $statuscss= 'priorityLow';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?>  <?php echo $row1[1];?></div></td>
                <td class="task-td" > <?php echo $task123;?></td>
                <td class="task-description"> <?php echo $row1[3];?></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php echo $row1[4];?></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php echo $row1[5];?></td>
                <td class="task-td" width="15"> </td>
            </tr>
<?php }?>

    </tbody>
        </table>

        <br><br>

     <div id="viewTask"  class="modal" style="display: none;">

          <div id="editTask">



       </div>
    </div>




        <script>
            //var modal = document.getElementById('viewTask');
    function myFunction() {
        var Task_Number = $(this).data('data');  
          $.ajax({  
                url:'select.php',  
                method:'POST',  
                data:{Task_Number:Task_Number},  
                success:function(data){  
            $('#editTask').html(data);
           document.getElementById('viewTask').style.display='block';}
           });

    }

     function closefunction(){
     document.getElementById('viewTask').style.display='none';
          }


 </script>
```

Select.php Code

```
<?php 

                     require('server.php');

                     session_start();

                      $task246 ='';
                    $task246 = $_POST['Task_Number'];
                    $modal123 = "select Tasknumber,Priority,Description,Duedate,Title, Status1 from Universe.Task where Tasknumber=$task246;";

                    $modalqry = mysqli_query($link, $modal123);
                    $output= '';

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($modalqry))
                        {
                            $Tasknumber_modal=$row[0];
                            $Priority_modal=$row[1];
                            $Description_modal=$row[2];
                            $Duedate_modal=$row[3];
                            $Title_modal=$row[4];   
                            $status_modal=$row[5];

                        }                                       
                        $output .='<table class="taskTableOpen">
            <tbody class="task-tbodyOpen">

            <tr class="task-tr">
            <td class="task-td"  id="backlog">';

            if ($status_modal=='backlog') {$statuscss= 'statusBacklog';} elseif ($status_modal== 'inprogress') {$statuscss= 'statusInProgress';} else{ $statuscss= 'statusDone';}
            $output.= '<div class="'.$statuscss.'">'.$status_modal.'</div></td><td class="task-td">';
            if ($Priority_modal=='HIGH') {$statuscss= 'priorityHigh';} elseif ($Priority_modal== 'MEDIUM') {$statuscss= 'priorityMedium ';} else{ $statuscss= 'priorityLow';}   
            $output.='<div class="'.$statuscss.'">'.$Priority_modal.'</div></td>
            <td class="task-td"></td>
            <td class="task-td">'.$Duedate_modal.'</td>
            <td class="task-td"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></td>
          </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <h1 id="title" value="swag">'.$Title_modal.'</h1>

            <p id="content" class="taskDescOpen">'.$Description_modal.'</p> 
            <button type="button" id="editBtn" class="taskEdit">Edit <i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>
        <p></p>

          <div class="containerComment">
             <textarea placeholder="Comment..." class="taskComment"/></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="reset" id="closebtn1" onclick="closeFunction()"class="closebtn">Close</button>
          </div>';

                        echo $output;

                        mysqli_close($link);



                        ?>
```

Comment: use `var Task_Number = $(this).data('value');` because the data attribute you want is called `data-value` not `data-data` ... i.e. why did you change that part of the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643371/when-i-click-on-a-row-in-my-table-the-function-does-not-run-and-open-a-modal-wi? I didn't tell you to change that

Comment: I tried that way and that did not work so started changing that value trying different things that I have found on other post. .

Comment: right ... how about `var Task_Number = this.dataset.value;`

Comment: also, check the page source *in the browser* to see what is in `data-value="..."`

Comment: oh, hang on `$(this)` is probably NOT going to work the way you've written the code - not sure really

Comment: try this code - https://pastebin.com/zdQ7jJiw or even this one https://pastebin.com/aNG8cbq0

Comment: I checked the page source in the browser and it says the correct select.php?Task_Number=18. I am not sure why

Comment: I've since discovered your issue ... it's with `this` being `window`, because you use `onclick` attribute - see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set an onclick function as an element attribute, `this` will NOT be the clicked element

```js
function myfunction() {
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(this));
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myfunction()">CLICK ME</div>
```

it's the window object

You can do this instead

```js
function myfunction(el) {
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(el));
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myfunction(this)">CLICK ME</div>
```

Now the `el` argument is the element clicked

Alternatively (and the way I would do it), if you add the click listener using javascript, like so

```js
$('.x').click(function(e) {
  console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x">CLICK ME</div>
```

Then `this` will be the element clicked

In your code, remove the `onclick="myFunction()"` and add a line of code to add an event listener for `click` ... i.e. `$('.task-tr').click(myFunction);`

So your code would end up

```
<table class="taskTable"  >
    <tbody class="task-tbody">
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($Table)){ $task123=$row1[2];?>
        <!-- removed onclick= -->
        <tr class = "task-tr" data-value="<?php echo $task123;?>">
            <td class="task-td"><input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"></td>
            <td class="task-td"> <?php if ($row1[0]=='backlog') {$statuscss= 'statusBacklog';} elseif ($row1[0]== 'inprogress') {$statuscss= 'statusInProgress';} else{ $statuscss= 'statusDone';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?><?php echo $row1[0];?></div></td>
            <td class="task-td"> <?php if ($row1[1]=='HIGH') {$statuscss= 'priorityHigh';} elseif ($row1[1]== 'MEDIUM') {$statuscss= 'priorityMedium ';} else{ $statuscss= 'priorityLow';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?>  <?php echo $row1[1];?></div></td>
            <td class="task-td" > <?php echo $task123;?></td>
            <td class="task-description"> <?php echo $row1[3];?></td>
            <td class="task-td"> <?php echo $row1[4];?></td>
            <td class="task-td"> <?php echo $row1[5];?></td>
            <td class="task-td" width="15"> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
 <div id="viewTask"  class="modal" style="display: none;">
    <div id="editTask">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    //var modal = document.getElementById('viewTask');
    function myFunction(e) {
        var Task_Number = this.dataset.value;
        $.ajax({  
            url:'select.php',  
            method:'POST',  
            data:{Task_Number:Task_Number},  
            success:function(data){  
                $('#editTask').html(data);
                document.getElementById('viewTask').style.display='block';
            }
        });
    }
    // set up click handler here
    $('.task-tr').click(myFunction);
    function closefunction(){
        document.getElementById('viewTask').style.display='none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Same error, Task_Number  is undefined index in php. Nothing changed.

Comment: can you `console.log(Task_Number)` in the javascript code, just after you've assigned it, to see if it's undefined there

Comment: Console logs the correct number so it is not undefined at that point. This is the correct way to use POSt right?   $task246 = $_POST['Task_Number'];

Comment: Your new answer worked, the only thing I changed thought was Method: 'POST' to type:'POST'. Thank you!

Comment: but your code used `method:'POST'` ... wow, what version of jquery are you using

Comment: I am using 1.8.1